# Audio having a weird behaviour while being played

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with playing audio when I press or click a button.

[Drum Machine](https://gamintor.github.io/DM_VanillaJS.github.io/)

It seems like my audio has a delay but I put a `audio.currentTime = 0`, so I don't know what's going on.

Here is my JS:

```js
const $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

const sounds = [
    {id:'Bass Drum', letter:'Q', src:'https://dight310.byu.edu/media/audio/FreeLoops.com/3/3/Free%20Kick%20Sample%2011-909-Free-Loops.com.mp3'}
];
let volumeVal = 0.5;

$('input[type=range]')[0].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    volumeVal = e.target.value / 100;
});

function main(url, name) {
    const audio = new Audio(url);
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.preload = "auto";
    audio.volume = parseFloat(volumeVal);
    audio.play();
    $('.name')[0].textContent = name;
}

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    function seter(id) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(`.${id}-but`)[0].classList.add('pressed');
            setTimeout(() => {
                $(`.${id}-but`)[0].classList.remove('pressed');
            }, 140);
        }, 0);
    }
    switch(e.key) {
        case 'q':
            main(sounds[0].src, sounds[0].id);
            seter('q');
        break;
    }
}

$('.q-but')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    main(sounds[0].src, sounds[0].id);
});
```

Comment: Can you fix your snippet into a [mcve]

Comment: I think the delay is just the audio file loading (check the "network" tab of the browser devtools). Just preload them when loading the page.

Comment: @mplungjan I already have cut down the size from 120 lines to this.

Comment: @Seblor I have opened a network tab and saw that my sounds have a big delay of 300ms ,on average. How should I fix it? I already put the `audio.preload = "auto";`

Comment: @Gamintor sure, you hae set preload, but there is nothing you preload until you press a button / key. You should create a hidden audio node for each audio file (with preload and the src already set) and play those instead of setting the src on a single audio node.

Comment: @Seblor "hidden audio node for each audio file", what do You mean by this?

Comment: @Gamintor by that I mean `audio` HTML elements that are either hidden through CSS, or just not added to the document. One for each audio file you need to load.

Comment: @Seblor Thank You. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, big thanks to @Seblor for providing me with the solution.

I solved my problem by creating audio node for each sound:

```html
<audio id="bass" preload="auto" src="https://dight310.byu.edu/media/audio/FreeLoops.com/3/3/Free%20Kick%20Sample%2011-909-Free-Loops.com.mp3"></audio>
```

And inside my JS file I added this event listener for every button:

```js
$('.q-but')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    const audio = $("#bass")[0];
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
});
```

Of course, now I could make my code less repetitive because I am doing this for all 9 buttons. And eventually I will.